# Service Oriented Architecture Interoperability

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, interop, soa

My main question is how and when Service Oriented Architecture(SOA) interoperability occures if we implement RESTful service with WebAPI?
Is we should do settings for that or it is intrinsic?

Comment: WebAPI exposes service operations over HTTP/S. This is the mechanism by which interoperability occurs. HTTP/S is a standard which means services running on different computing platforms can exchange information. This is the definition of interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very powerful as it deals with the root concepts of service orientation as such. Interoperability is intrinsic to a service or micro-service itself. Lets say a service in nature must be interoperable. It is always available to be orchestrated and composed to form a more complex functionality system.

Please refer to the soa-manifesto.org and the principles of service orientation, [interoperability](http://serviceorientation.com/serviceorientation/service_orientation_and_interoperability)

About REST is just HTTP web service. It is intrinsically inter-operable as HTTP definition you can compose the service, invoke it, is stateless. Hence Restful HTTP services are intrinsically inter-operable by definition.